# metricbeat agent running on ELK cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, metricbeat

Does metricbeat need always an agent running separately from the ELK cluster or it provides a plugin/agent/approach to run metricbeat on the cluster side?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to know if their is a way to monitor your cluster without installing a beat.

You can enable monitoring in the stack monitoring tab of Kibana.

[image]

If you want more, beats are standalone objects pluggables with logstash or Elasticsearch.
Latest versions of Elastic Stack (formally known as ELK ) offer more centralized configurations in Kibana, and the 7.9 version introduce a unified elastic agent in Beta to gather several beats in one and manage you "fleet" on agent within Kibana.

But information used by your beats are not directly part of Elastic (CPU, RAM, Logs, etc...)
So you'll still have to install a daemon on your system.